# "Too many SQL variables" error in django with sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm getting this error using sqlite3 in django:

> Exception Value: too many SQL variables

And I think the answer to it is this, [from here](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

> Many SQL programmers are familiar with using a question mark ("?") as a host
> parameter. SQLite also supports named host parameters prefaced by ":", "$", or
> "@" and numbered host parameters of the form "?123".

> To prevent excessive memory allocations, the maximum value of a host parameter
> number is SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER, which defaults to 999."

However, there's a remaining oddity that I don't understand, which is that the
same query runs fine from a django shell session (launched with `python manage.py shell`), but not when the call is made from my `views.py`.

These are the lines of code that are causing the error:

```
vals = Company.objects.filter(id__in=comp_ids).values('id', 'name').order_by('name')
names_map = SortedDict(vals)
```

where `comp_ids` is a set containing 1038 integer elements.

The exact same query, with an even greater no. of `comp_ids` (3800+) runs fine in
the django shell (launched with `python manage.py shell`) - the dictionary gets
created, and I could iterate through it.

I've tried breaking up `comp_ids` into sets of e.g. `[:996]` (that seemed to be the
limit before it barfed) i.e. `filter(id__in=comp_ids[:996])`, then the rest in
the next iteration, which would be consistent with the "no. of host parameters"
explanation.

But why would it work in the django shell but not from `views.py`?

**EDIT:** Some more information:
Entering the query into the sqlite shell (manage.py dbshell) returns the full
set of results with no errors, same as in the django shell (manage.py shell).

Here are the exact list of parameters (1039 elements) and the query, if you'd
like to know the details:

params

```
(2, 3, 4, 2053, 6, 7, 2732, 10, 3737, 13, 2063, 2064, 17, 18, 21, 2393, 2052, 29, 30, 32, 2456, 35, 36, 38, 40, 2396, 42, 2731, 45, 46, 2095, 3343, 49, 2098, 2252, 53, 54, 58, 59, 2058, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 72, 2123, 3426, 3344, 79, 80, 81, 85, 2134, 87, 91, 92, 95, 98, 2747, 2149, 102, 104, 106, 2155, 109, 110, 3773, 2455, 2165, 118, 122, 2171, 2172, 127, 134, 135, 137, 138, 2187, 2413, 145, 148, 2414, 2198, 2199, 152, 153, 154, 2204, 157, 2210, 163, 2417, 169, 170, 2219, 172, 173, 3279, 2077, 179, 180, 181, 2230, 2231, 184, 186, 187, 2237, 190, 191, 2240, 2241, 3787, 2245, 2246, 2247, 2248, 2249, 2251, 204, 205, 207, 208, 209, 210, 213, 214, 2263, 2265, 3450, 222, 2273, 2274, 2275, 228, 2277, 2811, 231, 234, 2283, 2284, 238, 240, 243, 248, 250, 2299, 2300, 254, 2303, 2305, 258, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313, 267, 269, 2318, 271, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2325, 278, 2327, 280, 282, 283, 285, 286, 287, 290, 2342, 295, 298, 2347, 2348, 2349, 2350, 2351, 304, 2353, 307, 309, 312, 318, 320, 321, 323, 326, 327, 328, 332, 333, 334, 2385, 338, 2387, 2388, 2389, 2390, 2391, 2392, 345, 2394, 347, 348, 350, 352, 354, 355, 356, 357, 359, 360, 2410, 364, 365, 366, 2415, 2416, 369, 2451, 373, 2422, 375, 377, 2426, 2428, 2429, 2430, 2432, 2433, 387, 2454, 391, 2441, 2443, 398, 399, 400, 401, 2553, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 413, 2462, 3628, 418, 2459, 420, 2469, 2470, 2472, 425, 427, 2476, 2461, 2483, 2485, 440, 441, 2490, 443, 444, 445, 446, 2496, 2497, 2499, 2501, 2502, 455, 2504, 2505, 459, 460, 2466, 2510, 463, 465, 466, 467, 469, 470, 2519, 2520, 2468, 474, 2529, 2531, 484, 486, 487, 488, 490, 491, 493, 2542, 2543, 2544, 497, 498, 499, 500, 2549, 502, 2551, 504, 505, 2554, 2555, 2556, 509, 2558, 511, 2560, 2562, 2475, 2564, 517, 2566, 2567, 2568, 2569, 523, 2572, 526, 527, 529, 536, 538, 539, 2588, 2589, 2590, 2596, 550, 552, 556, 2605, 2607, 2608, 2612, 565, 566, 567, 568, 580, 2634, 587, 2636, 2638, 2639, 2270, 595, 598, 2489, 605, 606, 609, 610, 2407, 615, 618, 619, 620, 2669, 2670, 2493, 2672, 2152, 628, 629, 630, 2680, 2682, 2684, 640, 641, 642, 2691, 645, 648, 650, 2699, 2700, 2701, 2702, 2703, 2705, 659, 2708, 661, 2712, 667, 2718, 2719, 2720, 2721, 2723, 2724, 2725, 2728, 681, 2730, 2614, 684, 2733, 2735, 2736, 689, 2739, 2741, 2746, 699, 701, 706, 707, 2757, 2759, 2760, 2508, 2763, 2766, 721, 2771, 725, 730, 2511, 732, 2170, 734, 2343, 743, 749, 2798, 2799, 752, 753, 2515, 756, 2078, 2807, 2808, 2412, 763, 2813, 766, 769, 2818, 2821, 2822, 779, 2861, 2833, 2834, 2835, 2836, 2837, 790, 802, 2852, 2854, 2856, 2550, 810, 2860, 813, 2862, 2863, 817, 2869, 2870, 2871, 824, 826, 2876, 829, 830, 2882, 836, 2885, 2886, 3574, 2890, 2892, 2893, 847, 2896, 2872, 2899, 2902, 2546, 2909, 2256, 2912, 2913, 870, 2920, 2921, 2922, 876, 2930, 887, 2937, 3903, 892, 893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 901, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 2884, 2970, 927, 2977, 2978, 2979, 2980, 2981, 2545, 941, 942, 2205, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 3014, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 3234, 2552, 980, 981, 982, 983, 985, 2895, 3038, 995, 996, 998, 2897, 2538, 2761, 3051, 1012, 1013, 3062, 3063, 3066, 2559, 3073, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030, 2421, 3080, 1036, 1038, 1039, 1040, 1041, 3092, 3246, 3853, 1050, 3099, 1057, 3109, 3112, 1067, 1068, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1078, 1081, 2491, 1086, 2229, 1088, 1089, 1090, 1091, 1092, 1093, 1095, 1096, 1097, 1098, 1099, 1100, 1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 1107, 1108, 1109, 1110, 1111, 1112, 3161, 1119, 3170, 2235, 3174, 3176, 3177, 1132, 1133, 1134, 1135, 1136, 3186, 1141, 3192, 3193, 3194, 3195, 3197, 3198, 2425, 1152, 1155, 1156, 3205, 2924, 3214, 1168, 1169, 1171, 1172, 1173, 1174, 1175, 1176, 3225, 1178, 3230, 1186, 1189, 1193, 1194, 1195, 1196, 3245, 1198, 1199, 1200, 1202, 2541, 3273, 1210, 3259, 1213, 1225, 1226, 1228, 1230, 2253, 3280, 3281, 1234, 1235, 1238, 1243, 1244, 1248, 1249, 3298, 3299, 1253, 3302, 2257, 3304, 3305, 3306, 3308, 1262, 2838, 3315, 3317, 3381, 1277, 1278, 3327, 3331, 3332, 1285, 2945, 1288, 1289, 1292, 1295, 1296, 1298, 3347, 3348, 3349, 1302, 3351, 3352, 3353, 1306, 1307, 3356, 1312, 3364, 1320, 3370, 3371, 3372, 3374, 3375, 1328, 3377, 3378, 3380, 1333, 1334, 3388, 3390, 3296, 3394, 3395, 2227, 1350, 2615, 1357, 1361, 1362, 3411, 3412, 3413, 1368, 2276, 1371, 1372, 3105, 1378, 2228, 3428, 3430, 3433, 1400, 1402, 1404, 3453, 3455, 3808, 1409, 3458, 3459, 1412, 1414, 1416, 1417, 1418, 1419, 1420, 2093, 3470, 1437, 3486, 1439, 2571, 3491, 3492, 3493, 1446, 2435, 1454, 1463, 3663, 3523, 1477, 1478, 1479, 1480, 1481, 1482, 3531, 1484, 1488, 1489, 1490, 3540, 1494, 1495, 1496, 3546, 3547, 2298, 1510, 1512, 3666, 1520, 1523, 2302, 1526, 1527, 3584, 1539, 1540, 1542, 1543, 1548, 1549, 3393, 1554, 1555, 1560, 1561, 3079, 1565, 2507, 3616, 3617, 1570, 3619, 3620, 3621, 3622, 1575, 3624, 2817, 3629, 3630, 1583, 1590, 1591, 1592, 2996, 3643, 3645, 2997, 3649, 2781, 3653, 3655, 1608, 3657, 2317, 1618, 3667, 1620, 3669, 1625, 2319, 3002, 2782, 1633, 1634, 3199, 3691, 3346, 3688, 1650, 1656, 3007, 3709, 3008, 1666, 2616, 3009, 2668, 2306, 3723, 3010, 2238, 1681, 1682, 1683, 1687, 3012, 3738, 2671, 1693, 3013, 1697, 1698, 2548, 3749, 3755, 3757, 3758, 2333, 1714, 1718, 3770, 3018, 1729, 3778, 3783, 1739, 1744, 3793, 1746, 1752, 1753, 1755, 3741, 3707, 1771, 1774, 2514, 1779, 2494, 3831, 1788, 2346, 3029, 3840, 3182, 2689, 1802, 1803, 2690, 1811, 1815, 1817, 3011, 2352, 1827, 2467, 1832, 3881, 1839, 1840, 2107, 1848, 1849, 2698, 2653, 1855, 1857, 1864, 1867, 1872, 1873, 3923, 1878, 1882, 1889, 3354, 1903, 1904, 2366, 1915, 1920, 1921, 1927, 1928, 1930, 1931, 3133, 1943, 1947, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1964, 1967, 1968, 1976, 2809, 3612, 1987, 1988, 1989, 3745, 1994, 2000, 2003, 2382, 2008, 3613, 2021, 2022, 3410, 3464, 2033, 2034, 2037, 2038, 2729, 2044)
```

query

```
'SELECT "screen_company"."id", "screen_company"."name" FROM "screen_company" WHERE "screen_company"."id" IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ORDER BY "screen_company"."name" ASC'
```

(Incidentally, you don't need to use pdb for that - django very helpfully
displays the backtrace in the browser (in render_to_response()?) when an error occurs, with a
full list of the local variables at each step, so you can see the full query
there.)

I had, however, previously tried stepping into the django code with pdb, and
found the error was actually originating from python's pysqlite2.dbapi2 (or
sqlite3.dbapi2) module, at line 200 of django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
```

(which was also in the helpful backtrace shown in the error page), where
Database is an alias for either pysqlite2.dbapi2, or sqlite3.dbapi2, depending
on your python version.

But I thought that was too far down the call stack to keep debugging (for now),
so decided to stop, and started thinking about workarounds and googling for
answers instead. :)

Comment: Could the Django shell be smart enough to know about the limit and automatically break up the query for you?

Comment: Breaking up the query would create race conditions.  It would be better to create a temporary table with one column and populate that.  Then the query is SELECT ...  WHERE column in (SELECT * FROM temptable).

Comment: Another reason that this could happen is doing prefetch_related on large querysets.

Comment: @dbw Can you please tell me how do I resolve this issue. Because I'm using sqlite. But I want to perform readonly operation.

Answer (score 27):

actually those limits are given here:
https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_limit_attached.html#sqlitelimitvariablenumber

with an explanation:

> Maximum Number Of Host Parameters In A Single SQL Statement
>
> A host parameter is a place-holder in an SQL statement that is filled
>   in using one of the sqlite3_bind_XXXX() interfaces. Many SQL
>   programmers are familiar with using a question mark ("?") as a host
>   parameter. SQLite also supports named host parameters prefaced by ":",
>   "$", or "@" and numbered host parameters of the form "?123".
>
> Each host parameter in an SQLite statement is assigned a number. The
>   numbers normally begin with 1 and increase by one with each new
>   parameter. However, when the "?123" form is used, the host parameter
>   number is the number that follows the question mark.
>
> SQLite allocates space to hold all host parameters between 1 and the
>   largest host parameter number used. Hence, an SQL statement that
>   contains a host parameter like ?1000000000 would require gigabytes of
>   storage. This could easily overwhelm the resources of the host
>   machine. To prevent excessive memory allocations, the maximum value of
>   a host parameter number is SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER, which defaults
>   to 999.
>
> The maximum host parameter number can be lowered at run-time using the
>   sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER,size) interface.

https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Do you mean if you have 1000000000 parameters? That would be an absurdly high number. However up to something such as 10000 might not be excessive.

Comment: Is there a reason for why it won't "inline" them before executing a query instead of passing them as 1k+ parameters? I don't understand why the above query wasn't simply `... IN (1, 2, 3, 42, ...)` instead of `... IN (?, ?, ? ...)`

Comment: @DanM. thats okay with number, but if you have strings you would like to parametrize them to prevent injection.

Answer (score 20):

*Googling this error message brought me here so adding my solution.*

In my case this error was caused by line:

```
Event.objects.all().delete()
```

Probably Django was trying to "DELETE WHERE id IN (?,?,?,..." and list of ids was to long.

Performance was not an issue for me so i solved this by:

```
while Event.objects.count():
    ids = Event.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)[:100]
    Event.objects.filter(pk__in = ids).delete()
```

Comment: Excellent! For better performance you don't have to limit yourself to 100 items at a time; I set it to 500 but you prob. can increase it closer to 999 or so (the above referenced SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER defaults to 999).

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to bypass this, it's an SQLITE limitation. Your query will run fine on MySQL however. But if you have to do this kind of query, you are most probably doing it wrong. Your mysql schema should be redone. And if you can't, then you may want to break this query into 100 of small queries.

Answer (score 2):

I hava found the same error when I run the line:

```
    Entry.objects.all().delete()
```

I solved the problem by

```
    while Entry.objects.count():
          Entry.objects.all()[0].delete()
```

I think it's a better idea than others.

Comment: This is not nearly as efficient as @fsw's answer, which bins by groups of queries.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I am not Django expert*

The problem is that in your query

```
vals = Company.objects.filter(id__in=comp_ids)...
```

you pass a bloated set of values and the underlaying engine cannot execute the query.
Fortunately [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), that you execute in that line, is [lazy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/loading.html). You an execute a SELECT and then filter the entries "manually" without big performance penalties.

It would look more-less like that:

```
# here you should do a proper session.query(CompanyTable)
vals_all = Company.objects

vals_filtered = (item for item in vals_all if item.id in comp_ids)
vals_ordered = sorted(vals_filtered, key=attrgetter('name'))
vals_final = [(v.id, v.name) for v in vals_ordered]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but when deleting just single row that had a large number of related rows in another table. Django was calling a cascading delete causing the problem, but since my code was only calling a single object delete, the solutions described in other answers could not be applied (unless I modified the Django library code, which I didn't want to do).

My solution was to first delete the related objects via raw sql query, then use the normal Django delete() on the parent object, all wrapped in a transaction.

Before:

```
object.delete() # Django tries to delete a large number of related object and fails
```

After:

```
from django.db import connection

Class MyObject:
    def delete_related(self):
        cur = connection.cursor()
        sql = 'delete from my_table where ...'
        cur.execute(sql, params)

...

with transaction.atomic():
    object.delete_related() # so that Django won't try (and fail) on its own
    object.delete()
```