# How to overcome "OperationalError: too many SQL variables"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to insert data frame of size `(8760, 1574)` into a table in `SQLite`. My code is below:

```
class DatabaseWorker(object):
    def __init__(self, db_name):
        self.db = db_name

    def create_table(self, table_name, column_names):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        q1 = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s' %(table_name)
        q2 = 'CREATE TABLE ' + table_name + ' ' + '(' + ', '.join(str(x) for x in column_names) + ')'
        cur.execute(q1)
        cur.execute(q2)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def insert_table(self, table_name, data):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db)
        data.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

cnx = DatabaseWorker("users")
cnx.create_table("user_activity", df_final.columns.values.tolist())
cnx.create_table("user_similarity_matrix", df_transformed.columns.values.tolist())
cnx.insert_table("user_activity", df_final)
cnx.insert_table("user_similarity_matrix", df_transformed)
```

Size of `df_final` is `(249238, 7)` and size of `df_transformed` is `(8760, 1574)`. There no error in inserting `df_final` but I am getting error while inserting `df_transformed`. The error is as below:

> ----> 5 cnx.insert_table("user_similarity_matrix", df_transformed)
>
> ---> 30         data.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
>
> pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
>                         index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
>                         chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
>
> OperationalError: too many SQL variables

One of the answers on ["Too many SQL variables" error in django witih sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106016/too-many-sql-variables-error-in-django-witih-sqlite3) there is a limit of 999 variables? Is there any way I can sidestep that. I will appreciate your suggestions. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER` [was increased in SQLite > 3.32.0](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) from 999 to 32766.

> 9. Maximum Number Of Host Parameters In A Single SQL Statement
>
>    [...]
>
>    SQLite allocates space to hold all host parameters between 1 and the largest host parameter number used. Hence, an SQL statement that contains a host parameter like ?1000000000 would require gigabytes of storage. This could easily overwhelm the resources of the host machine. To prevent excessive memory allocations, the maximum value of a host parameter number is SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER, which defaults to 999 for SQLite versions prior to 3.32.0 (2020-05-22) or 32766 for SQLite versions after 3.32.0.

This means that your `df_transformed` having 1574 columns should work as well in recent SQLite builds. However note that `SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=2000` and you don't have much room for growing the number of columns in your data frame.

> The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000. You can change it at compile time to values as large as 32767. On the other hand, many experienced database designers will argue that a well-normalized database will never need more than 100 columns in a table.
>
> In most applications, the number of columns is small - a few dozen. There are places in the SQLite code generator that use algorithms that are O(N²) where N is the number of columns.

Alternatives could be a custom document serialisation using [`pandas.DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_json) / [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) in a SQLite `TEXT` column, `pandas.DataFrame` `sqlite3` [adapter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-adapters-to-store-additional-python-types-in-sqlite-databases) and so on. Because `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH` is 1GB per row, serialisation affords much wider data frames.

Comment: Thank you, saaj. This will be very helpful in the future.